# Substitutes for provolone and cacciacavallo cheese in the UK

Tags: cheese

What can I use as an alternative to provolone and cacciacavallo cheese in the UK? Both have been difficult for me to find here.

Comment: That's a good duplicate for provolone, but doesn't cover caciocavallo. (Ironically, provolone is often suggested as a substitute for caciocavallo, though!)

Comment: @Erica in that case isn't this question two questions in one? In which case the part that's a dupe could be edited out leaving the caciocavallo portion only?

Comment: Any substitution that works for provolone is going to work for caciocavallo.  The two cheeses are very similar.

Comment: As we’re talking substitutes and the two cheeses in the question can be mutual substitutes, an answer for Provolone should cover Cacciacavallo.